# How RabbitMQ docker image from docker hub run locally?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

```
I want to use Rabbitmq from the docker hub in my application, I need to configure how the container will run locally. Basically, I need to get the URL so I can use it in my application.
```

I pulled the RabbitMQ:latest from docker hub.

```
docker pull rabbitmq
```

Then run with the command (pull & run):

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8081:15672 rabbitmq
```

Then I was trying to run in the browser with :

```
http://localhost:8081 or http://host-ip:8081
```

But *localhost refused to connect.*

Does anyone have any reference to getting this configuration?

Comment: use `5672:5672` instead of `8081:15672` then use `http://localhost:5672`

Comment: Thanks @omidh , it worked, I got the login page of RabbitMQ, but after login getting a PAGE UNRESPONSIVE error. any idea why??